# How to securely store resources in a web application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, security, mern

I am creating an application in the MERN technology stack. This project is a gallery of graphics. Some of the graphics are paid and some are free. I am wondering which way to store these paid images will be the most secure ? I put the free graphics in a static uploads folder stored on the server where the application is running. The path to the file is stored in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do it is to have the paid images in some storage that is not publicly accessible. Then you put some form of a api/proxy in front of it that can verify users. If user is verified you show the picture, if not you show something else.